# Leading Zeros in Text Input Fieldtype

Tags: fieldtype, entries, text-formatting

Is there any way to preserve leading zeros when using the text input field type? This is getting truncated. :(

0010250107 -> 10250107

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this by changing the expected content of your field from a number/integer to "any" which is basically a string and so will not be treated as a number.

[image: Set the Field Content to "All" to treat the input as a string]